# Going through Automate the boring stuff and I can't install pyperclip

Tags: python, installation, pyperclip

I am on MacOS 10.14.3, using python 3.12. I have gone through Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3

In IDLE, this is what happens:

```
import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you do `pip install pyperclip`?  Are you sure your pip belongs to the same Python that IDLE is running?

Comment: I believe they are the same. I do not have multiple versions downloaded. I entered install pyperclip into the IDLE shell when I received the error

Comment: From what you have shown you have entered `import pyperclip`, not `install pyperclip` into the IDLE shell. But in order to be able to import it, you first need to install it (outside IDLE).

Comment: I was under the impression I installed it. I went through Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pip3 on my mac. Clicking on pip, a terminal popped up. Is there a step I'm missing? Sorry, I'm very green at this

Comment: `pip list` will show the installed modules.

Comment: How would I view/where would I enter pip list?

Comment: I think I got it! I needed to enter 'sudo' before pip3 install. Thanks everyone!